# Unit testing that localStorage.getItem has been called on document ready?

Tags: javascript, dom, storage, sinon, qunit

I have the following code, whereby a localStorage item is checked on document ready. If a localStorage item has not been set yet, it's set:

```
$(document).ready(function () {             
   checkIfLoginTracked();                
})

function checkIfLoginTracked() {
   if (localStorage.getItem("loginHasBeenTracked") === null) {
         localStorage.setItem("loginHasBeenTracked", true);
   }
}
```

I am struggling to know how best to unit test this however?

I am using Qunit and Sinon and so far have been trying the following in the test block (spying on the local storage method and checking it's been called with the correct argument)

```
var spy = sinon.spy(window.localStorage, "getItem");
assert.ok(spy.calledWith("loginHasBeenTracked", true));
```

This is returning false and saying not called. I don't know if I am missing something obvious, or if it's perhaps because it's on `document.ready` that it's difficult to test? Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You are missing something obvious. You need to convert the "true" to true

Comment: @mplungjan thank you - what do you mean? They're both true and not "true" already, no?

Comment: "true" is thruthy but not === true - localStorage stores strings only

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan but this didn't work? I am trying to check that the "getItem" method was called ?

Comment: Thanks was not clear. I re-opened. Please update your question with a clear explanation. I am not sure how you would monitor a call to a native method

Comment: Can you please add the full test case? Including any setup/teardown? You should be testing your `checkIfLoginTracked` method, NOT `document.ready()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit test solution, test environment: `node`. If your test environment is `browser`, you don't need the `jsdom` module. And you should stub the `localStorage` object on `window` object rather than `global` object.

`index.js`:

```js
const $ = require("jquery");

$(document).ready(function() {
  checkIfLoginTracked();
});

function checkIfLoginTracked() {
  if (localStorage.getItem("loginHasBeenTracked") === null) {
    localStorage.setItem("loginHasBeenTracked", true);
  }
}
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const proxyquire = require("proxyquire");
const sinon = require("sinon");
const jsdom = require("jsdom");

describe("59840852", () => {
  before(() => {
    const html = '<!doctype html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8">' + "</head><body></body></html>";
    const url = "http://localhost";
    const document = new jsdom.JSDOM(html, { url });
    const window = document.window;
    global.document = window.document;
    global.window = window;
  });
  it("should set item", () => {
    const localStorageStub = {
      getItem: sinon
        .stub()
        .withArgs("loginHasBeenTracked")
        .returns(null),
      setItem: sinon.stub(),
    };
    global.localStorage = localStorageStub;
    const jqueryStub = { ready: sinon.stub().callsFake((handler) => handler()) };
    const $ = sinon.stub().callsFake(() => jqueryStub);
    proxyquire("./", { jquery: $ });
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly($, document);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(localStorage.getItem, "loginHasBeenTracked");
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(localStorage.setItem, "loginHasBeenTracked", true);
  });

  it("should do nothing if login has been tracked", () => {
    const localStorageStub = {
      getItem: sinon
        .stub()
        .withArgs("loginHasBeenTracked")
        .returns(true),
      setItem: sinon.stub(),
    };
    global.localStorage = localStorageStub;
    const jqueryStub = { ready: sinon.stub().callsFake((handler) => handler()) };
    const $ = sinon.stub().callsFake(() => jqueryStub);
    proxyquire("./", { jquery: $ });
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly($, document);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(localStorage.getItem, "loginHasBeenTracked");
    sinon.assert.notCalled(localStorage.setItem);
  });
});
```

Unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
  59840852
    ✓ should set item (93ms)
    ✓ should do nothing if login has been tracked


  2 passing (149ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.js      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.test.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59840852